# How to enable h3 in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, http3

How to configure/enable http3 in tomcat? Any documented steps would help. I checked tomcat official documentation but nothing could be found. Here is my current connector tag from server.xml -

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="mykeystorejks"
           keystorePass="****" server="Unknown"
            sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
            ciphers="!aNULL,!eNULL,!EXPORT,!DES,!MD5,!PSK,!RC4,!3DES,!CBC3,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
/>
```

Comment: Are you asking about a geospatial database or about HTTP/3? You have tagged both, which one is it? Does Tomcat support HTTP/3 already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Tomcat does not support HTTP/3.

If you really need HTTP/3 support then you would need to place Tomcat behind a reverse proxy that does support HTTP/3 and then proxy the requests to Tomcat over one of the supported protocols (AJP, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2).